# Bound textbox shows database value, but the 'Text' property is an empty string

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, textbox

I can't seem to find any answers on what I would think is a pretty basic problem. I have a textbox that is bound to a dataset that gets filled on form load. When I run the program the value from the database is displayed in the textbox.

However, the text property is an empty string. If I click in the field and then leave it, the text value is set. Reading from, and even writing to, the database through the table adapter is working fine. I just can't seem to get a value into the text property.

Here's the relevant code...

Code added by Visual Studio when I bound the field through the user interface:

```
this.appSettingsBindingSource.DataMember = "AppSettings";
this.appSettingsBindingSource.DataSource = this.dSAppSettings;
this.tbUsername.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", this.appSettingsBindingSource, "Username", true));
```

Here's the line from the form's load method:

```
this.appSettingsTableAdapter.Fill(this.dSAppSettings.AppSettings, CompanyID);
```

Comment: try the `Value` property

Comment: Phillip, I appreciate the suggestion, but the textbox control does not have a Value property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've worked around the problem, but I'm sure I've missed some fundamental step that led to this problem in the first place.

My bound controls are on two different tabs. So, I activated each tab and then set the focus to each control on the tab:

```
// Workaround: Focus() forces the dataset value into the bound property of a control

tabCtlSettings.SelectedTab = tabAccountSettings;  // Activate second tab
foreach (Control ctl in tabAccountSettings.Controls)
  ctl.Focus();

tabCtlSettings.SelectedTab = tabOptions;  // Activate first tab
foreach (Control ctl in tabOptions.Controls)
    ctl.Focus();
```

I know it's an awful band aid of a fix, but it'll have to do to get the project finished!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged` to the end of the binding statement.  I believe the default is `OnValidation`.

```
this.tbUsername.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", this.appSettingsBindingSource, "Username", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
```

Comment: I had previously tried this in desperation, however, it did not work. As I understand the Binding constuctor, the update mode is for the data source. I am not having difficulty updating the source, I am having difficulty updating the target, or bound control.

I validate the form before saving the values, so OnValidate works fine for me.  If I do place my mouse in each of the fields and then click my save button, it does successfully update the database.